# Trouble accessing object

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-models, django-views

I've been working on an issue all day and am at my wits end. I have two models with a manytomany relationship (bookmark, and boomark group). I am trying to access the bookmarks accosiated with the bookgroup in my view. When print the context to take a peak I get None returned. I've pasted the code below in a gist...any help would be so greatly appreciated.

models.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from itertools import chain
import datetime
import hashlib

from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager, PermissionsMixin
from django_mysql.models import JSONField, Model
from django.template.loader import render_to_string
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from django.utils import timezone
from django.conf import settings

class Bookmark(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    resource = models.ForeignKey("Resource", on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="bookmarks")
    bookmark_groups = models.ManyToManyField("BookmarkGroup")
    # meta
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('user', 'resource',)
        ordering = ('resource',)

    def __str__(self):
        return "{} | {}".format(self.user, self.resource)


class BookmarkGroup(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    slug = models.SlugField(null=False, unique=True)
    bmark = models.ManyToManyField(Bookmark)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

views.py

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
import json

from django.shortcuts import render, get_list_or_404
from django.http import JsonResponse
from django.views import View
from django.views.generic import DetailView

from app.serializers import BookmarkGroupSerializer
from app.models import Resource,Bookmark,ResourceShare,PrivateNote,BookmarkGroup
from app.views.resources import get_enriched_resources

class BookmarkGroupView(DetailView):
    model = BookmarkGroup
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(BookmarkGroupView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        print(context['object'].bmark.resource)
        return context
```

Answer (score 0):

The key here is ManyToMany relationship, but you are trying to access it like a single object.

```
 context['object'].bmark.all()[0].resource
```

OR

```
context['object'].bmark.first().resource
```

**UPDATED**:
With emptiness check

```
try:
  resourse = context['object'].bmark.all()[0].resource
except:
  resourse = None
```

OR

```
bmarks = context['object'].bmark.all()
resourse = bmarks[0].resource if bmarks else None
```

Comment: If I use  context['object'].bmark.all()[0].resource I get IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Meaning of this is your context['object'].bmark.all() is empty in your database, you can use ether try/except or checking for emptyness